# BigQuery - changed default for null fields? How to restore?

Tags: null, google-bigquery

It looks like BigQuery changed its behavior for conditions on `null` fields: they return now the `false` value and not null as it used to be not so long ago. I checked and the behavior changed for both Legacy and Standard SQL.

Check out this code:

```
#standardSQL
With data as (
 SELECT safe_cast(null as int64) as int_field
   union all
 SELECT 5 as int_field
   union all
 SELECT 10 as int_field
)
SELECT *, if(int_field in (5,7),1,0) as condition 
from
data
```

---

```
#legacySQL
SELECT *, if(int_field < 10,1,0) as condition 
from
( SELECT *
from
 (SELECT null as int_field)
   ,
 (SELECT 5 as int_field)
   ,
 (SELECT 10 as int_field)
)
```

Now it affects some existing views getting rid of `null`s -- and it's not the desired behavior.
Anyone knows how I can redefine the default values without going through every line of code and adding `if(field is null,null,if(other conditions...`?

[image]

Comment: "How to restore?" - if you believe it is an issue/bug - submit issue to issue tracker!

Comment: Created! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151541824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can still get your desired `nulls` with a slightly changed logic.

Something like:

```
#standardSQL
with data as (
 select safe_cast(null as int64) as int_field
   union all
 select 5 as int_field
   union all
 select 10 as int_field
)

select 
   *, 
   if(int_field in (5,7), 1, if(int_field is null, null, 0)) as condition
from
data
```

or

```
#legacySQL
select 
  *, 
  if(int_field is null, null, if(int_field < 10,1,0)) as condition 
from ( 
   select * from
   (select null as int_field),
   (select 5 as int_field),
   (select 10 as int_field)
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I do not want to do, as said in the last sentence of the question

Comment: I thought this little extra condition can ensure win-win in all cases (even if BQ reverts back to previous behavior), but yes, its totally your choice.

Comment: Yeah... But it implies that I need to look in hundreds of existing queries and views and find where I relied on this condition, so I'm rather reluctant doing that.